# the finite solution first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an equation: $xy'+ay=f(x)$, where a is positive constant and $f(x)\rightarrow b<\infty$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. I found the solution:
$y=\frac{C}{|x|^a}+\frac{b}{a}-\frac{1}{|x|^a}\int\limits_0^x f'(t)\frac{t^a}{a}dt$. And I need to show that there is only one finite solution as $x \rightarrow 0$. To do that I have to show that $\frac{1}{|x|^a}\int\limits_0^x f'(t)\frac{t^a}{a}dt \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$. But don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The limit is $\displaystyle \frac 00$, you can use L'Hôpital's rule. While differentiating the numerator use Newton-Leibniz integral rule. Might help you.

Comment: I think, if I use L'Hôpital's rule and Newton-Leibniz integral rule I'll get something like $\frac{1}{a^2}  \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0} x*f'(x)$, so I don't know the limit as I'm not able to assess the derivative.

Comment: Assuming you have done the calculations correctly. I can see that if you put $x=0$ in the above term that you got the limit becomes $0$. You don't have to worry about that derivative because it's multiplied with $0$. Isn't that right?

Comment: But what if $f’(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: Oh yeah! I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

Using an integration by parts you obtain:
$$\frac{1}{|x|^a}\int\limits_0^x f'(t)\frac{t^a}{a}dt=\frac{1}{|x|^a}\left((f(x)-b)\frac{x^a}{a}-(f(0)-b)\frac{0^a}{a} \right)-\frac{1}{|x|^a}\int\limits_0^x \left(f(t)-f(b) \right)t^{a-1}dt$$
so it is equivalent to show that $\frac{1}{|x|^a}\int\limits_0^x \left(f(t)-f(b) \right)t^{a-1}dt \to 0$. And:
$$\left| \frac{1}{|x|^a}\int\limits_0^x \left(f(t)-b \right)t^{a-1}dt\right| \leq \frac{1}{|x|^a} \sup_{t \in [0,x]} \left|f(t)-b \right| \int\limits_0^x t^{a-1}dt = \sup_{t \in [0,x]} \left|f(t)-b \right|$$
which goes to $0$ as $x \to0$.

---

Following the comments, here is more details about the [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts).

Let $$u(t)=f(t)-b$$ and $$v(t)=\frac{t^a}{a}$$.

Then $u'(t)=f(t)$ so:
$$\int\limits_0^x f'(t)\frac{t^a}{a}dt=\int_0^x u'(t) v(t) dt = u(x)v(x)-u(0) v(0)-\int_0^x u(t) v'(t)dt$$
and as $u(0)v(0)0$, $u(x)v(x)=(f(x)-b) \frac{x^a}{a}$ and $v'(t)=t^{a-1}$ we obtain:
$$\int\limits_0^x f'(t)\frac{t^a}{a}dt=\left((f(x)-b)\frac{x^a}{a}\right)-0-\int\limits_0^x \left(f(t)-f(b) \right)t^{a-1}dt$$

Comment: Please bear with my ignorance but I don't understand your integration. What is $f(b)$? Do you mean $f(0) \to b$? Also, are we allowed to put the limits separately(like you have done with the first part) while integrating a definite integral by parts ? Shouldn't we put the limits after the whole function has been integrated?

Comment: $f(b)$ is a mistake, it is $f(0)=b$. By the limits, do you mean the term $(f(x)-b)x^a-(f(0)-b)0^a$ ?

Comment: Yes, because I have never seen it done like that before, any references?

Comment: @paulplusx I have added more details about it and a reference to wikipedia, you can ask if I have made a mistake or if you want more details.

Comment: Aah, such a simple thing. Thank you for taking all the pain and explaining it to me.